# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'git rebase' y 'git merge'?

Tags: git, git-merge

Trabajo con Git y con frecuencia debo incorporar cambios de otras personas en las ramas en que trabajo. Cuando esto sucede hay quien me recomienda usar `git rebase` y otros `git merge`.

Por ello, me gustaría saber: ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `git rebase` y `git merge`?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16666089/1983854

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Resumen para lectores ávidos de conocimiento rápido: con `git rebase` tendrás un historial más claro, por lo que suele ser la opción preferida.

Cuando haces `git rebase`:

- los commits locales se eliminan de la rama temporalmente.
- se ejecuta un `git pull`.
- los commits locales se insertan nuevamente.

Esto quiere decir que todos tus commits locales aparecen al final, después de los commits remotos. Esto es, si haces `git log`, los commits de la rama que has *rebasado* aparecen como si fueran más antiguos, independientemente de cuándo se hicieran.

---

Supongamos que tienes 3 commits `A`,`B`,`C`:

[image: A-B-C]

Entonces viene Daniel y crea un commit `D`. Luego Enrique crea un commit `E`:

[image: A-B-C-D-E]

Obviamente, este conflicto debe ser resuelto de alguna forma. Para ello hay dos maneras:

**MERGE**:

[image: A-B-C-D-E-M]

Ambos commits `D` y `E` aún están allí, pero creamos un commit de unión (*merge commit*) `M` que hereda los cambios de ambos commits `D` y `E`. Sin embargo, esto crea la estructura en forma de *diamante*, que a mucha gente confunde.

**REBASE**:

[image: A-B-C-D-E-R]

Creamos un commit `R`, cuyo contenido es idéntico al del commit `M` descrito arriba. Sin embargo, nos cargamos el commit `E` como si nunca hubiera existido (se ve con los puntitos, en la línea evanescente). De acuerdo con esta anulación, `E` debería ser un commit local de Enrique y no debería haber hecho `push` a ningún repositorio.
La ventaja de este método es que se evita la forma de diamante y el historial permanece lineal, que es algo que la mayoría de los desarrolladores agradecen.

---

De forma menos visual pero más descriptiva, podemos referirnos a ello de la siguiente forma:

- `git-rebase` – Genera una serie de commits secuencialmente, de modo que puedan aplicarse directamente sobre la cabeza del nodo.

Cuando haces un `rebase` en tu rama, le estás diciendo a Git que haga como si hubieras cambiado de rama (`checkout`) de una forma limpia y que luego empezaste a trabajar a partir de allí. Esto convierte los cambios en algo limpio y conceptualmente simple que otra persona podrá revisar. Puedes repetir este proceso otra vez cuando hay nuevos cambios en la otra rama: siempre terminarás con una serie de cambios limpios en la cabeza de la rama.

- `git-merge` – Une dos o más historiales de desarrollo

Cuando haces un `merge` de una rama en la tuya, juntas el historial de ambas. Si después haces esto otra vez, empezarás a crear una serie de historiales intercalados: algunos cambios de Daniel, algunos de Enrique, algunos de Daniel... lo que puede ser lioso.

Así, hablando en plata, es como si dijéramos "tenemos dos padres, queremos un hijo".

> <sub>Esta respuesta incorpora contenido de las cuatro respuestas principales a [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16666089/1983854) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666418/1983854), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22639428/1983854), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25267150/1983854) y [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733192/1983854) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866438/1983854)).</sub>

Comment: El problema de usar rebase es: que sucede cuando Enrique va a ver los cambios que habia hecho en su commit? que ha desaparecido!!!, y Enrique empezara a lanzar "rayos y retruecanos"  y pestes, ya que no puede obtener el id del commit, y no puede volver a ver esos cambios. Por ello, mucha gente te recomentará usar **git merge**. Yo soy de la opinion de usar git merge.

Comment: @Jakala muy buen punto, con el que me he encontrado en alguna ocasión. Para esto lo que me ha gustado descubrir es el [`git merge --squash`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308816/1983854), que junta todos los commits de Enrique [en uno solo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551395/1983854). Especialmente útil cuando hay pull requests. ¿Lo conoces? ¿Tiene alguna contrapartida aparte de juntarlo todo?

Comment: no sabia de ese comando. Pero por lo que he podido leer aqui (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash) lo que hace es el rebase -l , manteniendo un commit indicando el mensaje. Creo que no es cuestion de que tenga contrapartidas, sino mas bien de como usas git. Pero parece buena idea. Lo probaré.

Comment: Algunos detalles: `git rebase` no hace pull (`git pull` se pude configurar para que haga rebase en vez de merge). Y, como regla general, no se debe hacer rebase de ramas **compartidas** (es técnicamente posiblle, pero si se reemplaza la historia de dicha rama compartida, el trabajo que estén haciendo otras personas  sobre la rama antes del rebase tiene que moverse a la nueva rama _sin incluir las revisiones a las que se les hizo rebase_, cosa que es posible, pero no me gustaría tener explicarle a desarrolladores que no estén claros en el concepto de lo que ocurrió con la rama compartida).