# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un repositorio bifurcado (forked)?

Tags: git, github, git-fork, git-clone

Supongamos que hice un fork en un proyecto de GitHub. Trabajé un poco con él, hice un pull request y se aceptó.

Posteriormente, me di cuenta que el repositorio ha ido avanzando y que mi versión quedó bastante atrás. Ahora quiero hacer otro PR pero no puedo hacerlo porque mi versión difiere bastante de lo que está en el HEAD del repositorio inicial.

¿Debo eliminar mi copia local o hay alguna forma de actualizarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Extraído de [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/1983854)</sub>

#### Puedes configurar tu repositorio para hacer un *rebase* del repositorio original :)

En el repositorio local, el clon, puedes añadir el repositorio original de GitHub como "remote".

Después, puedes hacer un "fetch" para traerte todas las ramas del repositorio en su estado actual, para finalmente *rebasar* tu trabajo para así poder continuar trabajando con la versión *upstream* (la última en el repositorio original).

Paso a paso, se trata de:

- Añade el remote, llamándole por ejemplo "upstream":

  ```
  git remote add upstream https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git
  ```
- Haz "fetch" de todas las ramas de ese remote, para así poder *trackearlas* como por ejemplo "upstream/master":

  ```
  git fetch upstream
  ```
- Asegúrate de estar en master:

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```
- Reescribe tu rama master de manera que todos tus commits que no estén en upstream/master se escriban encima de esa otra rama:

  ```
  git rebase upstream/master
  ```

Si no quieres reescribir la historia de tu rama master (por ejemplo, porque otra gente puede haberlo clonado) entonces debes utilizar `git merge upstream/master` (véase [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'git rebase' y 'git merge'?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/83624/83)).  Sin embargo, para que los ulteriores *pull requests* sean lo más limpios posible, probablemente sea mejor hacer un *rebase*.

---

Si rebasaste tu rama en `upstream/master`, puede que debas forzar el push cuando hagas push en tu propio repositorio bifurcado en GitHub. Se trataría de usar:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Solamente necesitar usar `-f` la primera vez que hagas push después de haber hecho el rebase.