# ¿Una vez que hice un PR de un repo, debo borrar mi fork?

Tags: git, github

Trabajando con un proyecto libre en GitHub, hice un fork del mismo, hice unos cambios y pedí un PR, el cual fue aceptado.

Actualicé mi fork [upstream](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) y seguí haciendo otros cambios, para luego volver a hacer otro PR.

En ese momento, me dí cuenta de que mi nuevo PR incluía todos los commits que ya había hecho, e incluso todos los archivos.

Se suponía que al hacer el upstream, ya debería haber estado al día, pero o fallé en algo, o mi fork nunca se enteré del PR aceptado.

Para evitar eso, hice un branch con solamente los archivos modificados. Sin embargo, el PR de ese branch sigue incluyendo todos los commits que hice.

No así con los archivos, solo va el modificado.

Entonces, ¿cuál es la forma correcta de trabajar cuando uno hace un fork de un proyecto?

¿Debería haber ejecutado algún comando más además del upstream? ¿o solamente tengo que vaciar mi fork después de cada PR y volver a trabajar como si fuera de cero?

Comment: cuando decís que "actualizaste tu fork", qué comando ejecutaste?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/, ahi edito

Comment: Pregunté lo mismo unos días antes, supongo que porque ambos estamos haciendo PR en lo mismo :) [¿Cómo puedo actualizar un repositorio bifurcado (forked)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/145784/83)

Comment: @fedorqui son muy similares, pero fijate q ya habia hecho todo eso. Faltaba aclarar q nunca hay q trabajar sobre tu master si no siempre sobre un fork del mismo y hacer los pr desde ahi. Si no todo pr va con todos los cambios de vuelta. No probe con el rebase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suena a que vas a estar colaborando con este proyecto por un largo tiempo, no a que querés arreglar un bug y desaparecer.

En ese caso, podés hacer lo siguiente:

1. Nunca tocar `master`. En tu fork, `master` refleja el estado del proyecto original.
2. La primera vez, configurá un remote `upstream` que apunte al proyecto original, haciendo `git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git`.
3. Hacer todos tus cambios siempre en una branch. Imaginemos que estás trabajando en la branch `feature-guau`. Podés hacer push tranquilo, todo eso queda en tu fork.
4. Una vez que querés mandar un PR, hacés un PR de `tufork/feature-guau` a `proyecto-original/master`.
5. El mantainer te pide que trabajes en tu PR, vos cada cambio que hacés lo seguís subiendo a tu branch (eso actualiza el PR)
6. Una vez que el mantainer mergea el PR, pasa a estar en *su* master... pero no en el tuyo!
7. Lo que tenés que hacer ahora es traerte el `master` de `upstream`. Para eso:

   - Hacé `git checkout master` (eso hace que pases a trabajar en *tu* `master` (que está desactualizado).
   - Hacé `git fetch upstream` (eso hace que tu computadora "sepa" lo que hay en `upstream/master`, pero no hace cambios)
   - Hacé `git reset --hard upstream/master`. Eso hace que tu `master` valga lo mismo que el master del repositorio original. Como tu PR fue mergeado, lo trajo.
   - Por último, tenés que actualizar tu fork... para eso, podés hacer `git push -f`. Eso va a hacer que tu fork apunte a exactamente el mismo lugar que el proyecto original.

El paso 7 lo podés hacer en cualquier momento, independientemente de si tu PR fue mergeado o no... lo que hace es sincronizar `master`.

Comment: este tipo de informacion esta documentada de la misma forma en git o github o esta por parte???

Comment: no, este es sólo uno de los workflows posibles... en particular, este es el que se me ocurrió y me resulta más cómodo... pero cómo podes ver [en la pregunta de Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/6740/10927) hay otras opciones