# git merge no actualiza

Tags: git

Quisiera saber cual es el flujo para actualizar una rama a `develop`, ya que estoy teniendo problemas.

Desde la rama `develop` hice:

```
git checkout -b feature/test
```

Realicé los cambios en la rama `feature/test` y luego hice commit y push a `feature/test`.

Al pasar el tiempo la rama `develop` se actualizó entonces para actualizar mi rama hice:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature/test
git merge develop
```

Y aquí empezó mi problema ya que al hacer el `git status` estos archivos de `develop` se pusieron en la lista a ser commiteados y cuando hice `git add`, commit y push; al meterme en github y realizar un compare entre `develop` y `feature/test` resulta que me aparecen en la `feature/test` el cambio inicial, es decir, el archivo cuando hizo merge detecta un cambio en el archivo que no corresponde con `develop`.
Entonces en github aparece en mi rama los cambios mezclados con la supuesta actualización a `develop`.

Comment: fijate si esta te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/155381/324 (no es un duplicado, pero es algo parecido)

Comment: [git merge](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-B%C3%A1sicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tenés la branch creada `develop`:

1. `git checkout -b feature/test` para crear la nueva branch `feature/test`
2. `git commit -a -m "nueva branch"` para commitear los nuevos cambios en tu nueva branch.
3. `git push`
4. `git checkout develop` ir nuevamente a tu branch `develop`
5. `git merge feature/test` copias en tu branch `develop` los cambios de la otra branch.
6. `git push` y ya con esto deberías tener los cambios aplicados a tu branch `develop`.

---

**Más info** en [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-B%C3%A1sicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar).

Comment: En realidad quiero saber como puedo tener mi rama feature/test actualizada con develop cuando otros desarrolladores actualizaron develop

Comment: Lo podés hacer haciendo un `git checkout feature/test && git pull && git checkout develop && git merge feature/test`. Actualizás la branch de dónde vas a mergear, vas a tu branch `develop` y luego mergeas.