# Seria posible hacer dos pull request distintas a un mismo repositorio en GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-push

He comenzado a hacer pull requests a otros repositorios, antes ya hacía commits a mis propios proyectos. El problema que tengo es que en este repositorio en concreto (que es una lista de ejercicios), para hacer la pull request te pide que escribas el número del ejercicio y el lenguaje.
Cada ejercicio se presenta con un archivo distinto en carpetas distintas.
Ahora tengo una pull request con dos commits y no encuentro ninguna información al respecto de como hacer dos pull request distintas.

[image: Pull request con dos commit]

Obviamente el segundo commit apareció ahí, intentando hacer otra pull request. Tengo mas ejercicios por presentar y no quiero subirlos todos en la misma pull request.

Espero que se haya podido entender mi duda. Gracias de antemano ;D

- sergioJKS

Comment: no tengo claro si es el mismo problema, pero fijate aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155381/una-vez-que-hice-un-pr-de-un-repo-debo-borrar-mi-fork

Comment: Pues parece que tengo que repasar un poco como funciona pero en esa pregunta he encontrado este enlace (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145784/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-actualizar-un-repositorio-bifurcado-forked) que parece que funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor sería hacer una branch nueva por cada ejercicio, vos tenes el repo clonado en tu PC, creas una branch nueva desde "main" y trabajas el ejercicio 9 y haces PR, despues creas otra branch y trabajas en el ejercicio 10 y haces otra PR (si te interesa tener el main actualizado deberias hacer esto antes de crear el PR:

- git checkout main (te vas a la branch main clonada en tu PC)
- git pull (te traes todo lo nuevo de main en github)
- git checkout - (volves a la branch anterior, osea "ejercicio 09")
- git rebase main (rebaseas tu branch con lo nuevo de main si hay algo, pueden aparecer conflictos pero tenes que solucionarlos, es parte de trabajar en repos con otra gente)